# 504 Receive Failure- In RestFul WCF for Complex Type

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I am working on a Wrapper WCF to make existing WCF restful. I have tested couple of methods with complex types as well. The service returns a JSON successfully.

I have a service proxy class created to consume our old WCF service. But When I try to retrieve values of a type of Service reference class even though it doesn't show an exception the values are not returned to the client either. in Client when i check from fiddler it shows me a 504 Receive Failure.

```
   public Provider LoadProviderById()
        {
            using (ServiceClient client = ServiceFactory.Create())
            {
                Provider result = client.LoadProviderById(new Guid("{71502b58-6ba8-e111-aeae-00262d08b36a}"));
                return result;
            }
        }
```

**Provider type is a auto generated class in my Service proxy.**

Below is my interface of my WCF method.

```
   [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       UriTemplate = "/LoadProviderById",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string LoadProviderById();
```

Thanks a heap for any help.

Comment: Why did you instantiate the client proxy with ServiceFactory.create() function? Assumed this function located in your new WCF(Restful style) project. Why didn’t you use the default constructor to call the old service?  In my opinion, this method is used to call the old WCF service by using client proxy so that return the result to your new Restful service, is that right?

Comment: ServiceFactory.create() is returning a ServiceClient with authentication details. It is just a extention to the ServiceClient Proxy.

Comment: Yes you are right using this method I call the old WCF. The Provider class is a auto generated class in the Service Proxy. It does not have [DataMember] [DataContract] Attributes.

Comment: What I did was I created a another class with the Same attributes and mapped without a mapper. it works fine. But I cant use the AutoMapper inside. It doesnt return results and even I cant debug the WCF method.

Comment: DataContract/Service contract should be consistent with the server-side. it should be decorated by the [DataContract] or will result in the serialization error, that is no data.

Comment: Thanks. That means I have to reuse the auto Generated classes in the Service Proxy. I will have to create another set of mapping classes.